# Saving pandas DataFrame with nullable integer data type to HDF file (format='table')

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pytables, hdf

How can one save pandas DataFrame with nullable integer data type to an HDF file in the 'table' format?

```py
# input data
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(index=list(range(2)), data={'x':[np.uint8(1)]*2}, dtype='UInt8')

df.to_hdf('temp.h5', 'data', format='table')
# raises the following exceptions:
# AttributeError: module 'tables' has no attribute 'Uint8Col'
# Exception: cannot find the correct atom type -> [dtype->UInt8,items->Index(['x'], dtype='object')] module 'tables' has no attribute 'Uint8Col'

# 'fixed' format does not work either:
df.to_hdf('temp.h5', 'data', format='fixed')
# raises the following exception:
# TypeError: objects of type ``IntegerArray`` are not supported in this context, sorry; supported objects are: NumPy array, record or scalar; homogeneous list or tuple, integer, float, complex or bytes
```